# How can I remove Japanese characters from a string?

Tags: python, unicode

As per the title, I'd like to create a list of unicode in Python without having to type/copy-paste every unicode character I want.

For context, I want to delete all the Japanese characters from a string. (This includes kanji, hiragana, and katakana.) This string changes, so the specific Japanese characters inside of it will change, too. Currently, I am trying to do this by creating a list of all Japanese characters and then a for loop that replaces those characters with an empty string.

My code goes as follows, with `str_compounds` as the string and `banned_ja_char` as the forthcoming list of Japanese characters:

```
sub_list = [banned_ja_char, "【", "】", ",", "(", ")", "e.g.", "etc."]

# removing substring list from string
for sub in sub_list:
    str_compounds = str_compounds.replace(sub, '')
```

What methods could I use to remove all Japanese characters in the `str_compounds` string? Is it possible to compile a list of all Japanese characters (in unicode or otherwise) without just having a huge list of every individual unicode character? Alternatively, is there something similar to the `range()` function that I could use in this situation?

Comment: Look up the Unicode character range(s) for the characters you don't care about and filter the string using ord(c) for each character?

Comment: Alternately, see the unicodedata module.

Comment: You can generate the strings from their numeric code points with something like `[chr(x) for x in range(100, 200)]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace japanese characters with regex:

```
import re

s = """The Japanese writing system consists of two types of characters:
the syllabic kana – hiragana (平仮名) and katakana (片仮名) – and kanji (漢字)"""

hiragana = re.compile('[\u3040-\u309F]')
katakana = re.compile('[\u30A0-\u30FF]')
CJK = re.compile('[\u4300-\u9faf]')

s = hiragana.sub('', s)
s = katakana.sub('', s)
s = CJK.sub('', s)
```

result:

```
The Japanese writing system consists of two types of characters:
the syllabic kana – hiragana () and katakana () – and kanji ()
```

Comment: @ Tom McLean your `sub()` functions work, but I am wondering, what is the difference between `s = hiragana.sub('', s)` and `s = re.sub(hiragana, '', s)`?